# Regex: replacing consecutive groups with lookbehind

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regexp-replace

Let's say I have a string like this:

```
input_string = "foo ab-123 ab-456"
```

and I would like to clean it up by replacing every ab-xxx group by something generic, but *only* if the whole string starts with "foo".
If it was just one group, I could do this (in Python):

```
pattern = re.sub(r"(?<=foo) (ab-\d{3})", "<ab-xxx>", input_string)
```

But how do I do that for all groups, keeping the positive look behind condition in mind?

Comment: Possible in PyPi `regex` module but not in `re` module.

Answer (score 4):

Does it have to be *one* regex? If not,
you can break the task into two steps:

```
s = "foo ab-123 ab-456"
if s.startswith("foo"):
    s = re.sub(r"ab-\d{3}", "<ab-xxx>", s)
```

Above example gives s = `foo <ab-xxx> <ab-xxx>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a callback if you want everything happen in a single call:

```py
import re

def apply_masking(string):
  masked = re.sub(
    r'ab-\d{3}',
    lambda match: '<ab-xxx>' if match.string.startswith('foo') else match[0],
    string
  )

  return masked
```

Note that the callback will be called everytime a match is found, which means it will check the condition many times. Also, this piece of code is not exactly readable, whereas ["*readability counts*"](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/). That being said, you might want to use the solution suggested by @Socowi.

Alternatively, if you have no qualms over using a third-party module and/or a relatively complex regex, you can use the `regex` module for its non-fixed width lookbehind feature:

```py
import regex

def apply_masking(string):
  masked = regex.sub(r'(?<=^foo.*)ab-\d{3}', '<ab-xxx>', string)

  return masked
```

```
(?<=^foo.*)    # Match                    but only if the whole string starts with "foo".
ab-\d{3}       #       "ab-" and 3 digits
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/jxMkAq/1) (ECMAScript).

Or, if you prefer PCRE's `\K` and `\G`:

```
(?:            # Match either
  ^foo         # "foo" at the start of the string
|              # or
  \G(?!^)      # the position at the end of the previous match
)              # followed by
.*?            # anything, as few as possible,
\K             # (all of which we forfeit entirely)
ab-\d{3}       # then "ab-" and 3 digits.
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/jxMkAq/2) (PCRE2).